# Threejs - rotating the camera by 90 degrees, not objects

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

In my project there are a lot of objects in the scene so I'd rather rotate the camera than the objects. How can I do that? I use an OrthographicCamera, which means I work on 2D.

Current camera position (example left)

```
const camera =  new OrthographicCamera(0, width, 0, height, 0, 20);
camera.position.set(x, y, 1);
camera.clearViewOffset();
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

On the right is what I would like to achieve...

[image]

When I use `camera.rotation.z = Math.PI * 0.5;` Objects disappear behind viewport because my camera is set to the top left corner. Unfortunately, the camera settings is due to the coordinates it gets from BE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your frustum has 0,0 at the top left you need to add some other parents to the camera move its rotation point.

```js
const {
  Object3D,
  OrthographicCamera,
  Scene,
  Renderer,
  GridHelper,
  WebGLRenderer,
  MathUtils,
} = THREE;
const {
  lerp,
} = MathUtils;

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const {width, height} = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
const scene = new Scene();

const camera = new OrthographicCamera(0, width, 0, height, 0, 20);
// cameras look down -Z so this camera is looking from 20 to 0
camera.position.z = 20;

const cameraBase = new Object3D();
const cameraPivot = new Object3D();
cameraBase.add(cameraPivot);
cameraBase.position.set(width / 2, height / 2, 0);
cameraPivot.add(camera);
cameraPivot.position.set(-width / 2, -height / 2, 0);
scene.add(cameraBase);


addRect('red',    -10, -10, 5,  20,  20);
addRect('cyan',    20,  20, 5,  20,  20);
addRect('green',  100,  50, 5,  25,  30);
addRect('yellow', 130,  70, 6, 100,  50);
addRect('orange', 170,  90, 7,  50,  75);
addRect('white',    1,   1, 5, 298, 148);

function addRect(color, x, y, z, width, height) {
  // make a 1x1 unit grid
  const grid = new GridHelper(1, 1, color, color);
  // move it so it starts at 0,0 and goes to 1,1
  grid.geometry.applyMatrix4(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(0.5, 0, 0.5));
  // grids are in x,z plane. rotate to x,y plane
  grid.rotation.x = Math.PI * -0.5;
  // position it
  grid.position.set(x, y, z);
  // make it the size we want in pixel units
  grid.scale.set(width, 1, height);
  scene.add(grid);
}

const renderer = new WebGLRenderer({canvas});


function render(now) {
  cameraBase.rotation.z = (now * 0.001);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body { background: #444; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.124/build/three.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Cool! we are close! could you please simplify your code a little? get rid of the animation because my version is static (and I rotate the camera after clicking on the button) and I don't really understand why you are making the object3d

Comment: Maybe you should [read some tutorials](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-scenegraph.html). The `Object3D`s let us move the camera to the center, rotate it, then move it back to the top left corner so it works for the given projection matrix. Also, No, I will not change the code. It should be trivial for you to remove the animation and set `cameraBase.rotation.z` to some `Math.PI * 0.5` or `Math.PI` or `Math.PI * 1.5` based on whatever inputs you want.

Comment: Now I have another problem .. everything works fine, but when I transfer a photo with a threejs (as a layer), threejs does not follow the photo: /

Answer (score 2):

Try it with:

> camera.rotation.z = Math.PI * 0.5;

```js
const aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
const frustumSize = 2;

const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(0.5 * frustumSize * aspect / -2, 0.5 * frustumSize * aspect / 2, frustumSize / 2, frustumSize / -2, 0.01, 10);
camera.position.z = 1;
camera.rotation.z = Math.PI * 0.5;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

scene.add(new THREE.AxesHelper());

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.124/build/three.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your idea rotates the camera but objects disappear (they are somewhere high). And this is happening because the coordinates for these objects are defined based on the top left corner (I can't change it) :/ `new OrthographicCamera(left: 0, right: width, top: 0, bottom: height, near: 0, far: 20);`

Comment: any other idea? :)